# Testing using Junit and Mock put request

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'am trying to do a test on the put request and it gives me the null Pointer error just in this type of request I don't kow why please could someone help me , here is my controller :

```
@PutMapping ("/update/{id}")
    public Entreprise updateEntreprise(@PathVariable Long id,@RequestBody Entreprise entreprise ) {
       Entreprise e=entrepriseService.getEntreprise(id);
       e.setDescription(entreprise.getDescription());
       e.setNom(entreprise.getNom());
       e.setNumberCertificats(entreprise.getNumberCertificats());
       e.setNumberClients(entreprise.getNumberClients());
       e.setNumberYears(entreprise.getNumberYears());
       e.setNumberCollaborators(entreprise.getNumberCollaborators());
       entrepriseService.updateEntreprise(e);
        return e;
    }
```

and for the test method :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = EntrepriseController.class, secure = false)
public class TestsEntrepriseController {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @MockBean
    EntrepriseService entrepriseService;
 @Test
    public void givenEntrepriseURIWithPut_whenMockMVC_thenVerifyResponse() throws Exception {
        Entreprise entreprise = new Entreprise();
        entreprise.setId(1);
        entreprise.setNom("oumaima");
        entreprise.setDescription("description");
        entreprise.setNumberCertificats(12);
        entreprise.setNumberClients(15);
        entreprise.setNumberCollaborators(20);
        entreprise.setNumberYears(12);
        Services services = new Services();
        services.setNom("cloud");
        services.setId(1);
        Set<Services> allServices =  new HashSet<>(Arrays. asList(services));
        entreprise.setServices(allServices);
        mockMvc.perform(put("/entreprise/update/1")
                .contentType(IntegrationTestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(IntegrationTestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(entreprise))
        )
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(content().string("{\"fieldErrors\":[{\"path\":\"title\",\"message\":\"The title cannot be empty.\"}]}"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mock two calls from `entrepriseService`

1. for getEntreprise(id)
2. for updateEntreprise(e)

Try running below code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = EntrepriseController.class, secure = false)
public class TestsEntrepriseController {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @MockBean
    EntrepriseService entrepriseService;
 @Test
    public void givenEntrepriseURIWithPut_whenMockMVC_thenVerifyResponse() throws Exception {
        Entreprise entreprise = new Entreprise();
        entreprise.setId(1);
        entreprise.setNom("oumaima");
        entreprise.setDescription("description");
        entreprise.setNumberCertificats(12);
        entreprise.setNumberClients(15);
        entreprise.setNumberCollaborators(20);
        entreprise.setNumberYears(12);
        Services services = new Services();
        services.setNom("cloud");
        services.setId(1);
        Set<Services> allServices =  new HashSet<>(Arrays. asList(services));
        entreprise.setServices(allServices);

        Mockito.when(entrepriseService.getEntreprise(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(new Entreprise());
        Mockito.when(entrepriseService.updateEntreprise(Mockito.any(Entreprise .class))).thenReturn(entreprise);

        mockMvc.perform(put("/entreprise/update/1")
                .contentType(IntegrationTestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(IntegrationTestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(entreprise))
        )
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(content().string("{\"fieldErrors\":[{\"path\":\"title\",\"message\":\"The title cannot be empty.\"}]}"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing you mock the service call.
Add - Mockito.when(entrepriseService.getEntreprise(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(new Entreprise())